# How did I access the middle element of the stack if you can't access the middle element

Tags: rust, stack

I'm reading [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) document, and it says that ***The stack stores values in the order it gets them and removes the values in the opposite order. This is referred to as last in, first out. Think of a stack of plates: when you add more plates, you put them on top of the pile, and when you need a plate, you take one off the top. Adding or removing plates from the middle or bottom wouldn’t work as well!***

So how does this work

```
fn main() {
    let _x = 1;
    let y = 2;
    let _z = 3;
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

Thanks for helping, sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: See what is a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack); this is not specific to Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, they are explaining how a *call stack* works. When a function `a()` calls function `b()`, you can imaging `a()` allocates some memory in the call stack and so does `b()`. While `b()` is being executed, the memory allocated by `a()` stays as is. When `b()` returns and now `a()` continues its execution, it could allocate some more memory on the stack. When a function (*any* function) finishes, its memory is freed.

In call stacks each function's data should be seen as a separate stack element. Those elements are called *stack frames*. In your example you have 3 variables but only 1 element.

Also note that stack frames have variable size. For example, one frame might have 7 variables and take 48 bytes, while another might only have 1 variable, which allocates 100 KB (imagine a big array, for instance).

The memory in a given stack frame also resembles a stack in a way, in that you can't just insert or pop out a variable from the middle just like that, as that would require other variables' memory addresses to shift. However, you can read or write data from/to the entire stack frame. Even in a relatively low-level language like Rust, many of those thing are somewhat hidden from you, but it's definitely helpful if you understand how things work underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Every function needs a specific amount of RAM to hold all variables in this function. These are called frames. Frames are stacked, **not the variables** in them.
Every time you call a function, a new frame is allocated. Every time you leave a function, the frame for this function is dropped.

The Function-Stack has nothing to do with accessing variables in the same frame.